# Error while using authorization in SoapUI

Tags: soap, soapui, weblogic12c

I am trying to test my SOAP webservice running on weblogic 12c (which is not installed locally) using SoapUI as a client. Without authorization everything works fine, but when I implement very simple UserToken on server and do every step described here:

https://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/authenticating-soap-requests.html

then I've got following error:

```
<faultcode>wsse:InvalidSecurityToken</faultcode>
<faultstring>Security token failed to validate. weblogic.xml.crypto.wss.SecurityTokenValidateResult@211ca945[status: false][msg UNT Error:Message Created time past the current time even accounting for set clock skew]</faultstring>
```

Also I've looked to the http log of SoapUI and I've noticed something strange there:

```
Tue Mar 20 09:15:52 CET 2018:DEBUG:>> 
 <soapenv:Header>
  <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="..." xmlns:wsu="...">
   <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-374B6AAD9B07D377D515215337525091">
    <wsse:Username>user</wsse:Username>
    <wsse:Password Type="...#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
    <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="...#Base64Binary">urRvoAYbjjovfD0OQqvJ6g==</wsse:Nonce>
    <wsu:Created>2018-03-20T08:15:52.464Z</wsu:Created>
   </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
 </soapenv:Header>
```

The time of log (which is current one) is different then in `<wsu:Created>` tag. I don't know if it is important, but I am in UTC+01:00 time zone.

#### EDIT

I've give up with SoapUI and I've implemented my own Java client with authorization using `CredentialProvider`:

```
((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put(WSSecurityContext.CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_LIST, credentialProviders);
```

And then it was the same! So probably it isn't SoapUI problem, but something else.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException:
Client received SOAP Fault from server: Security token failed to validate. weblogic.xml.crypto.wss.SecurityTokenValidateResult@37b70a09[status: false]
[msg UNT Error:Message Created time past the current time even accounting for set clock skew] Please see the server log to find more detail regarding exact cause of the failure.
    at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:193)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:131)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.StubHandler.readResponse(StubHandler.java:253)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:203)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:290)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:119)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:92)
    ...
```

When I've looked to the message using Wireshark, time in header was also decrease by one hour. That is really strange and I have no idea what is going on. How am I supposed to test my webservice using authorization? Locally I am using Windows 7, but my Weblogic is running on CentOS 7. As I said both are set to UTC+01:00.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I finally menage to solve this issue. It turns out that server time is late for 2 minutes comparing to the local machine time. Webservice requires time between client and server cannot be larger then few seconds. When I adjusted time everything is working properly.

Additionally, current time in log `Mar 20 09:15:52 CET 2018` and time in message `2018-03-20T08:15:52.464Z` are equal, but just in different format.